# How to interact with android device through a script?

Tags: android, linux, scripting, android-scripting, android-shell

I need a bump in the right direction here.

I want to write a script that will scroll up or down, maybe unlock the screen ( no lockscreen security set ) every 30 minutes or so. Also if possible I'd like for it to press the next button on my YouTube app because the music stops every hour or so and since I'm in my studio I dislike my workflow being interrupted just to press next. Now I don't know much about android so I don't know where to start with this. Maybe a cron-job? a shell script?

Comment: If your device is rooted then [Is there a way to record and playback a set of touches?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/45121/3573) would be a starting point. On a non-rooted device there is no cron or shell script available to the user. If you aren't writing an Android app, check the answers on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) for possible direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Linux/macOS-based OS then the mix cron-job plus shell script is definitely a very good start.

Considering that the requirement is to automate the interaction with your app my suggestion is to create a script using the [AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) and with few lines of code you can programmatically [scroll lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28058207/implement-infinite-scrolling-in-androidviewclient), [click buttons](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/master/examples/click-no-id-button.py) etc.

No root required.